# Retrieve data from database based on selected Dropdown value using PHP and jquery AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, sql, ajax

I've UPDATED MY CODE BELOW AND IM GETTING "500 (INTERNAL SERVER ERROR)" on my php code.

I'm fairly new to PHP and jQuery, Ajax, and I've been having a hard time trying to find a example on the internet that could lead me to solving my problem. anyone kind enough to explain to me how would I be able to display data from a database into a html TABLE based on the value of the selected dropdown, kind of a filter.

I've already managed to load all the data from the database and it works, I've tried to look for an example online but couldn't find any.

ADDING CODES:
HTML CODE:

```
                <select name="countryN" id="countryCB">
                <?php
                while($rows = $resultSet->fetch_assoc())
                {
                    $country = $rows['Country'];
                    echo "<option value='Test'>$country</option>";
                }
                ?>
                </select>

                <input type="button" class="srchbtn" value="Seach">
            
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item-container">
            <div id="items">
                <table id="brtable">
                    <thead>
                        <tr class="tblrow" id="headers">
                            <th>BR-Name</th>
                            <th>Country</th>
                            <th>Data Stream</th>
                            <th>Region</th>
                            <th>Actions to be taken</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody id="tableresult">

                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
```

PHP CODE:

```
<?php   
$connect = mysqli_connect('127.0.0.1', 'root', '', 'testdb'); 
$countryN = $_POST['Country'];
$brfilterresult = ("SELECT Business_Rule_Name, Country, Data_Stream, Region,         
ActionNeeded FROM businessrulestbl WHERE Country='".$countryN."'");


$result = $connect->query($brfilterresult);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo "<tr><td>" . $row['Business_Rule_Name'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['Country'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['Data_Stream'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['Region'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['ActionNeeded'] . "</td></tr>";
}
}
?>
```

JS code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#countryCB').change(function(){
    var countryName = $(this).val();
    $.ajax({
        url:"../php/getbr.php",
        method: "POST",
        data: {countryName:countryName},
        success: function(data){
            $('#tableresult').html(data);
        }
    });
});
});
```

I just want someone to explain to me how would I be able to achieve my goal in a detailed manner, explaining each part. a sample source code would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make some correction in your code .

1.)  In select drop down option in HTML code

```
echo "<option value='$country'>$country</option>";
```

2.) In javascript code (missing # for calling id of element)

```
 $(document).ready(function (){
        $('#countryCB').on('change', function() {
            fetchRecordsfromDB(this.value);
            // alert(this.value);
        });
        });
```

3.) In PHP script (missing 'id' argument in $_REQUEST[]) and string quotation in select query

```
$countryN = $_REQUEST['id'];

 $brfilterresult = ("SELECT Business_Rule_Name, Country, Data_Stream, 
 Region, ActionNeeded FROM businessrulestbl WHERE Country='".$countryN."'");
```

I hope it will help you.
And let me know if you have more assistance.
happy coding :)

Comment: hi, i tried what you suggested but still it is not working.

Comment: $countryN = $_REQUEST['Country'];
$brfilterresult = ("SELECT Business_Rule_Name, Country, Data_Stream, Region, ActionNeeded FROM businessrulestbl WHERE Country='".$countryN."'");


$result = $connect->query($brfilterresult);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "<tr><td>" . $row['Business_Rule_Name'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['Country'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['Data_Stream'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['Region'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['ActionNeeded'] . "</td></tr>";
    }
}

Comment: and this is my js:$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#countryCB').change(function(){
        var countryName = $(this).val();
        $.ajax({
            url:"../php/getbr.php",
            method: "POST",
            data: {countryName:countryName},
            success: function(data){
                $('#tableresult').html(data);
            }
        });
    });
});

Comment: hey Lorenzo Carlo Naguit  just pass same variable name in ajax  request which you get in $_REQUEST[] in you php

Comment: So as i can see in your js and php script just replace in javascript data: {countryName:countryName} to data: {Country:countryName}

Comment: ITS WORKING! THANK YOU SO MUCH! could you care to explain why? and what caused it not to work in the first place so that i could avoid such things. THANK YOU!

Answer (score 0):

Okey. So you need some Javascript code to do this.
First, Make dropdown in you HTML and create an Ajax method and pass the dropdown selected value into it. Then keep this data in your PHP sides and execute your SQL query and show the result on your HTML page.

For example:

```
<select>
    <option value="1">One</option>
    <option value="2">Two</option>
</select>
```

Javascript:

```
$('select').on('change', function() {
  fetchRecordsfromDB(this.value);
});

function fetchRecordsfromDB(data){
  $.ajax({
      url: "your_php_file_url.php",
      cache: false,
      type: "POST",
      data: {id : data},
      success: function(html){
        $("#tbale").append(html);
      }
  });
}
```

PHP Side:

```
your_php_file_url.php

if (isset($_POST["id"]) && !empty($_POST["id"])) {
    $id = $_POST['data'];
}
```

Now you could execute your SQL the $id variable.

Comment: hi, i tried what you said and it still doesn't work, could you kindly take a look at the codes that i used above. maybe you could point out what im doing wrong. thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
function fetchRecordsfromDB($id){
  $.ajax({
      url: "your_php_file_url.php",
      cache: false,
      type: "POST",
      data: {id : $id},
      success: function(data){
        $("#tbale").html(data);
      }
  });
```